# Using label* to append enumitem labels but resetting the font

Tags: formatting, enumitem

I'm trying to create a legal-like list that has numbering like `1.`, `1.1.`, etc., except where the top level numbers are bolded, and the rest aren't.

Currently I have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{questions}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[questions,1]{label=\textbf{\arabic*.}}
\setlist[questions,2]{label*=\arabic*.}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

    \item Top level (number should be bolded)

    \begin{questions}

        \item Second level (whole number should be in normal font)

    \end{questions}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

which gives me:

[image: tex output]

So the second level has correctly appended a normal-font number onto the label from its parent, but it also kept the bolding in the parent's number (which I don't want).

I tried adding the `font=\normalfont` option to the second `questions` level, but that didn't have any effect.

Is there a good way to remove formatting from the parent label before appending to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the `font` key for the first level:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{questions}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[questions, 1]{label=\arabic*., font=\bfseries}
\setlist[questions, 2]{label*=\arabic*.}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

    \item Top level (number should be bolded)

    \begin{questions}

        \item Second level (whole number is in normal font)

    \end{questions}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would declare a formatting command and then change that formatting command `before` any deeper levels are reached.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\questionformat}{\textbf}

\newlist{questions}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[questions,1]{label=\questionformat{\arabic*.}}
\setlist[questions,2]{label*=\arabic*.,before={\DeclareRobustCommand{\questionformat}{}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
  \item Top level (number should be bolded)
  \begin{questions}
    \item Second level (whole number should be in normal font)
    \item Second level (whole number should be in normal font)
  \end{questions}

  \item Top level (number should be bolded)
  \begin{questions}
    \item Second level (whole number should be in normal font)
    \item Second level (whole number should be in normal font)
  \end{questions}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Since the hierarchy stores expanded versions of higher levels, `\DeclareRobustCommand` avoids expansions and therefore preserves the formatting command (making it changeable). However, don't use a `\ref`erence to one of the nested elements...

Comment: Ah, that's really cool. Kind of overkill for just the bold/non-bold application, but I'll definitely keep it in mind for more complex label formatting. Thanks!